# Cannot uninstall "Samsung Update Plus"

Tags: windows, uninstallation

In windows 7, I try to uninstall and receive the following message:

```
"Samsung Update Plus is running. Please exit the program and try again."
```

When I try to open the program it shows:

```
"Samsung Update Plus is in automatic mode. Please try again later."
```

How can I turn off this automatic mode? I terminated all services and closed all processes I could and nothing. Can someone help me get rid of this "awesome" samsung program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by myself. Seens like the program stuck on a reboot and did not finished a operation. I manually executed "C:\Program Files (x86)\Samsung\Samsung Update Plus\SUPBackGround.exe" and it finished the installation. Only after that I was finally able to remove it.